# how to use cgrect in a nsarray loop

Tags: ios, nsarray, cgrect

Trying to create a for loop with an nsarray of uiimageviews but cant seem to get the cgrectmake to work.

```
Location = CGRectMake(10, 10, 97, 110);
NSArray *cardImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:car1,car2,card3,car4,car5,car6,car7,car8,car9,car10,car11, nil];
for (UIImageView *image in cardImages) {

    image.frame = Location;
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ace.png"];
}
```

Comment: Please clarify. Your code looks fine, though it’ll give each image view an identical frame. Are you trying to have the frame change from one image view to the next?

Comment: Aside: you can use modern objective-c language to neaten up your code. I.e. `NSArray *cardImages = @[car1,car2,card3,car4,car5,car6,car7,car8,car9,car10,car11];`

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you are setting the same frame to all `UIImageView`'s.
Try to change frame origin each iteration:

```
NSArray *cardImages = @[ card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10,card11 ];
for (int i = 0; i < [cardImages count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *image = cardImages[i];

    // Each iteration new frame will have bigger x position (0, 10, 20...)
    image.frame = CGRectMake(10 * i, 10, 97, 110);
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ace.png"];
}
```